# Marker does not show up when I put the marker inside a array.map(){} function

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, async-await, leaflet

**Hello everyone**

Today I came to this beautiful platform with a very bad problem.
I have an application that uses a leaflet map and on those map I show Realtime markers from firebase.
but now I have made some extra functionality but now the markers wont show up anymore I looked through all of stack overflow but I could compare nothing with my problem. my problem is the  wont show up anymore and I have no clue why that happened

**this is the old code that showed a Marker**

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './LiveRouteTile.scss';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import markerIconPng from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"
import {Icon} from 'leaflet'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import firebase from "../../../firebase"
import {createApiEndpoint, Endpoints} from '../../../api/index';
import axios from "axios";


  

const LiveRouteTile = ({type}) => {
    const [RuuviTag, setRuuviTag] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    let [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState('')
    

    
 
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("RuuviTag");
   function getData(){
      setLoading(true);
      ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

        const items = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
          items.push(doc.data());
          console.log(items);
      });
  setRuuviTag(items);
  setLoading(false);
    });
  }
   
    useEffect(()=> {
      getData();
    }
      , []);
    return (
        <div className="route-tile">     

            
<Card className="route-card" >
                <CardContent className="route-card-content">
                 {loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : (<MapContainer className="map" center={[52.09, 5.10]} zoom ={8}>  
                    <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    {RuuviTag.map((tag) => (
                      <div key={tag.MAC}>
        
                      <Marker position={[tag.Latitude.replace(/,/g, '.') , tag.Longitude.replace(/,/g, '.') ]} icon={new Icon({iconUrl: markerIconPng, iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41]})} >
                    <Popup>
                   <h1>{tag.MAC}</h1>
                    </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    
                     
          
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    ))}</MapContainer>)}
                     </CardContent>
            </Card>
                
           
        </div>
    )

                    }

export default LiveRouteTile
```

in the code you will see next I expanded the array with decrypted data and a string for checking boundaries, I think it may have to do with that I use some functions a sync now but I cant find it.
I don't get errors the only problem is when the marker is inside the Ruuvitag.map() function it wont show but when I put it out of the .map() function it will show with static values. but even in .map() using only hardcoded properties of the marker it still wont show

**Broken Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './LiveRouteTile.scss';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import markerIconPng from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"
import { Icon } from 'leaflet'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import firebase from "../../../firebase"
import { createApiEndpoint, Endpoints } from '../../../api/index';
import axios from "axios";
import { ControlPointDuplicateOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';




const LiveRouteTile = ({ type }) => {
  const [RuuviTag, setRuuviTag] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);



  async function PostRawData(rData) {
  
    return axios.post("apilink", { rawData: rData }) //i changed the api link for pricacy reasons

  }

  async function checkBoundaries(rdata) {

    try {
      const response = await PostRawData(rdata)
      console.log(response)
      const data = response.data
      if (22.00 > data.temperature && data.temperature > 4.00) {
        console.log('if')
        return { data: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-blue.png' }
      }
      else {
        console.log('else')
        return { data: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png' }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }

  }


  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("RuuviTag");




  function getData() {
    setLoading(true);
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      
      const items = [];
      console.log(querySnapshot)


     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let item = doc.data()
        Promise.all([
          PostRawData(doc.data().RawData),
          checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData),
        ]).then(function (result) {
          item.decryptedData = result[0].data;
          item.colorIcon = result[1].data;
          console.log(item);
          items.push(item);
        })
      });


      setRuuviTag(items);
      console.log(items)
      console.log('hi')
      console.log(RuuviTag);

      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
  console.log(RuuviTag)//this is the log from the picture below
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }
    , []);
    
    return (
        <div className="route-tile">     

            
<Card className="route-card" >
                <CardContent className="route-card-content">
                 {loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : (<MapContainer className="map" center={[52.09, 5.10]} zoom ={8}>  
                    <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    
                    <Marker position={[9.0,9.0]} icon={new Icon({iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41]})} >
                    <Popup>
                      
                   <h1>jaap</h1>
                    </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    
                    {RuuviTag.map((tag) => (
                      <div key={tag.MAC}>
                        {console.log(tag)}
        
                      <Marker position={[tag.Latitude.replace(/,/g, '.') , tag.Longitude.replace(/,/g, '.') ]} icon={new Icon({iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41]})} >
                    <Popup>
                   <h1>{tag.MAC}</h1>
                    </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    
                     
          
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    ))}</MapContainer>)}
                     </CardContent>
            </Card>
                
           
        </div>
    )

                    }

export default LiveRouteTile
```

[CodeLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agT9r.png)

[image]

Anybody any clue what I have done wrong/or know another way to fix this issue.
Thank you in advance.
this is my first post btw so give feedback if i asked a good question and what can improve.
have a nice day (:

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` does not support async calls so we need to change it to a `for` loop. This is how the whole code would look like:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./LiveRouteTile.scss";

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import markerIconPng from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";
import { Icon } from "leaflet";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import firebase from "../../../firebase";
import { createApiEndpoint, Endpoints } from "../../../api/index";
import axios from "axios";
import { ControlPointDuplicateOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";

const LiveRouteTile = ({ type }) => {
  const [RuuviTag, setRuuviTag] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function PostRawData(rData) {
    return axios.post("apilink", { rawData: rData }); //i changed the api link for pricacy reasons
  }

  async function checkBoundaries(rdata) {
    try {
      const response = await PostRawData(rdata);
      console.log(response);
      const data = response.data;
      if (22.0 > data.temperature && data.temperature > 4.0) {
        console.log("if");
        return {
          data: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-blue.png",
        };
      } else {
        console.log("else");
        return {
          data: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png",
        };
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("RuuviTag");

  function getData() {
    setLoading(true);
    ref.onSnapshot(async (querySnapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      console.log(querySnapshot);

      const list = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let item = doc.data();
        list.push(item);
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const item = list[i];
        const result = await Promise.all([
          PostRawData(doc.data().RawData),
          checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData),
        ]);

        item.decryptedData = result[0].data;
        item.colorIcon = result[1].data;
        console.log(item);
        items.push(item);
      }

      setRuuviTag(items);
      console.log(items);
      console.log("hi");
      console.log(RuuviTag);

      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
  console.log(RuuviTag); //this is the log from the picture below
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="route-tile">
      <Card className="route-card">
        <CardContent className="route-card-content">
          {loading ? (
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
          ) : (
            <MapContainer className="map" center={[52.09, 5.1]} zoom={8}>
              <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              />

              <Marker
                position={[9.0, 9.0]}
                icon={
                  new Icon({
                    iconUrl:
                      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png",
                    iconSize: [25, 41],
                    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                  })
                }
              >
                <Popup>
                  <h1>jaap</h1>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>

              {RuuviTag.map((tag) => (
                <div key={tag.MAC}>
                  {console.log(tag)}

                  <Marker
                    position={[
                      tag.Latitude.replace(/,/g, "."),
                      tag.Longitude.replace(/,/g, "."),
                    ]}
                    icon={
                      new Icon({
                        iconUrl:
                          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png",
                        iconSize: [25, 41],
                        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    <Popup>
                      <h1>{tag.MAC}</h1>
                    </Popup>
                  </Marker>
                </div>
              ))}
            </MapContainer>
          )}
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LiveRouteTile;
```

We could also optimise it a little bit more by adding tha Promise.all to another Prmise all and do all requests in parallel and then use the data from there. But that fast fix should also work.